# NSCompoundPredicate not working as I want

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm building an expense manager and I have a **search** function with filters. For each filter selected, I append the respective predicate to an array of predicates for the **fetchedResultsController**. In my filters I have the options "Budget" and "Expense". The following code shows how I append the predicates.

```
    if filterCell[0][0] {
        predicatesArray.append(NSPredicate(format: "type == %@", "budget" as NSString))
    }
    if filterCell[0][1] {
        predicatesArray.append(NSPredicate(format: "type == %@", "expense" as NSString))
    }
```

Going back to the main tableview,I got this line of code:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: predicatesArray)
```

This is working just fine when only one budget or expense is picked, when they are both chosen, the tableview is empty (It's obvious, **type** can't be both "**budget**" and "**expense**") so I switched to `orPredicateWithSubpredicates`. Now if I pick "**budget**" in my filter and press OK, I still get the expenses entries and vice-versa because this viewcontroller contains  a default predicate (User gets to this view when he picks a period of dates, like 13.11 - 16.11 for example) and using the `orPredicateWithSubpredicates` does nothing since my date predicate will always be true, the only option being the `andPredicateWithSubpredicates`

What should I modify in my code so it can work properly?

Comment: You need to use `orPredicateWithSubpredicates` when allowing multiple types. But make sure you do not create a compound predicate if there is only one predicate in the array.

Comment: In my case I needed the `andPredicateWithSubpredicates` because I have a default predicate already for dates (when user select a period of dates) so  using the `orPredicateWithSubpredicates` pretty much did nothing since I already had a default predicate. I already solved it and posted as answer

Comment: You didn't mention anything about other predicates in your question so your answer (and your answer below) don't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Yes. It is my fault, I will edit my question right now for those who encounter the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. The problem was when setting the predicates not applying them.The correct way is the `andPredicateWithSubpredicates` and the way I applied the predicate is with this code:

```
    if filterCell[0][0] && filterCell[0][1] {
        predicatesArray.append(NSPredicate(format: "(type == %@) OR (type == %@)", "budget" as NSString, "expense" as NSString))
    } else if filterCell[0][0] {
        predicatesArray.append(NSPredicate(format: "type == %@", "budget" as NSString))
    } else if filterCell[0][1] {
        predicatesArray.append(NSPredicate(format: "type == %@", "expense" as NSString))
    }
```

Comment: This is unclear. There is no use of `andPredicateWithSubpredicates` in this answer.

Comment: Yes in the given case there is no use to it, but I realized I already had a default predicate and using `orPredicateWithSubpredicates` canceled my other subpredicates (since it will always be true)

Comment: Same was happening for me - this helped me figure out what was going on.